# Issue executing updatetool glassfish in Debian

Tags: java, glassfish, debian

I have installed glassfish 4 and it works pretty well but few minutes ago I tried to execute `updatetool` but I get this error:

```
./updatetool: 283: ./updatetool: /home/mazzy/glassfish4/updatetool/bin/../../pkg/python2.4-minimal/bin/python: not found
---------------------------------------------------------------
There was an error running

/home/mazzy/glassfish4/updatetool/bin/../../pkg/python2.4-minimal/bin/python

You are running on a 64 bit Linux distribution and the 32 bit Linux
compatibility libraries do not appear to be installed. In order to use
the Update Center tools you must install the 32 bit compatibility libraries.

On Ubuntu (and possibly other Debian based systems) please install the
ia32-libs package. On RedHat 4 (and other RPM based systems), you may
need to add multiple 'compat' runtime library packages. Please see the
Update Center Release Notes for more information
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

My system is Debian 7.1.0 Wheezy 64 bit.

What do you suggest to do? Please don't say to install `ia32-libs` package because I have already tried to install it bit it could not be installed in my sistem.

**EDIT**

This is the next error I get after having installed ia32-libs for i386 architecture:

```
GlassFish Update Tool does not support running in "it_IT.utf" locale.
Attempting to use English locale.
WX import error.  Verify the WX widgets are in the PYTHONPATH.
The following can be reported to GlassFish Update Tool 2.3.5 Development Team <dev@updatecenter.java.net>.

Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/home/mazzy/glassfish4/updatetool/vendor-packages/updatetool/common/boot.py", line 283, in init_app_locale
    import wx
  File "wx/__init__.py", line 45, in ?
  File "wx/_core.py", line 4, in ?
 ImportError: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: impossibile aprire il file oggetto condiviso: File o directory non esistente
```

Comment: Then you need to figure out why the `ia32-libs` package won't install on your system, since the lack thereof appears to be your problem

Comment: Ok I partially solved the problem. I have to install ia32-libs configure dpkg for the i386 architeture. Now the error has changed

Comment: Problem solved: I need to install libgtk2.0-0:i386

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a reference on installing the updatetool on glassfish 4,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060532/how-to-install-updatetool-on-glassfish-4-64bit-reference
I haven't run into the issues with the libraries you mentioned (rather then some others), so feel free to complete.

Answer (score 0):

In Debian 7 the you will need to indicate to dpkg the additional architecture to be able to install 32 bit libraries. Use:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then update the repository cache and install the desired packages indicating the i386 architecture.

```
aptitude update

aptitude install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Doing this for each library indicated in the error messages. In my experiencie: libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386, libidn11:i386, libjpeg62:i386, libsm6:i386, libpangox-1.0-0:i386

Answer (score 0):

I have:
   *Linux version 3.10-2-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.7.3 (Debian 4.7.3-6) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.10.5-1 (2013-08-07)*

and I couldn't update any lib related to "i386" because it a testing source, but! I have Glassfish (very updated) on my Windows so I stop the domain on Debian and copy/paste the whole folder /modules and done!